# Issue with page not erasing

Tags: pages

I am trying to fix a friends wordpress site and can not figure this out. 
The issue is: My friend recently made a new home page for his site, mainly because he moved his business and needed to announce the changes. So he created a new page we will call "New home" and erased "old home". The problem is, old home will not go away! It does not show in the "pages" builder, but seems to be cached on the specific theme he purchased, because it also does not show up if you switch themes. Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: This is a little confusing. Are you going to `Settings -> Reading` and setting the new Front Page to the "New Home" and it's not updating? Did you empty Pages Trash?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about the current setup, but in general, I would suggest logging into your friend's WP Admin Dashboard and going to Appearances > Customize > Static Front Page and selecting the "New Home" page like so:

[image: Customize Front Page]

If you are using any caching plugins, then also be sure to purge the cache from them so that you are able to see the updated home page. :)